# $1.class and $2.class not Serializable exception in jgroups

Tags: java, jgroups

I am creating a demo stock exchange distributed program in Java using jgroups as middleware. My Stock class has a priority queue which has a comparator, and results in `Stock$1.class` and `Stock$2.class` along with `Stock.class`. Jgroups can send only serializable data but from what I understand `$1.class` and `$2.class` result from inner classes that are inferred because of comparator's and are not serializable thus causing exceptions with JGroups, can someone help me as to how to make them serializable too or some other tweek to not to make it look like inner classes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Stock implements Serializable
{
    public String name;
    public String symbol;
    public int shares = 10000;
    public int price = 100;

    public PriorityQueue<Order> sellList = new PriorityQueue<Order>(100, new Comparator<Order>()
    {
        public int compare(Order oldOrder, Order newOrder)
        {
            int i = oldOrder.price;
            int j = newOrder.price;
            if(i > j)
                return 1;
            else if(i < j)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    );

    public PriorityQueue<Order> buyList = new PriorityQueue<Order>(100, new Comparator<Order>()
            {
                public int compare(Order oldOrder, Order newOrder)
                {
                    int i = oldOrder.price;
                    int j = newOrder.price;
                    if(i > j)
                        return -1;
                    else if(i < j)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Stack->     java.io.NotSerializableException: Stock$2
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
 at java.util.PriorityQueue.writeObject(PriorityQueue.java:686)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang

Answer (score 3):

Your anonymous inner classes only implement `Comparator`. In order to implement `Comparator` *and* `Serializable`, you should convert them to static nested classes, e.g.

```
public class Stock implements Serializable {

    private static class OrderComparator implements Comparator, Serializable {
        public int compare(Order oldOrder, Order newOrder) {
            int i = oldOrder.price;
            int j = newOrder.price;
            if(i > j) {
                return 1;
            } else if (i < j)
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private PriorityQueue<Order> sellList = new PriorityQueue<Order>(100, new OrderComparator());
}
```

Not only will this fix your immediate problem, it arguable also makes the code more readable.

Incidentally, the above comparator can be rewritten much more succinctly:

```
        public int compare(Order oldOrder, Order newOrder) {
            return oldOrder.price - newOrder.price;
        }
```

Comment: +1 I should point out that the two Comparators are not the same. The `-1` and `1` are reversed in the top and bottom in the OP.  However, the same concept can still be applied, and the readability (and reusability) of extracting into a private static class are still gained.

Comment: I also would like to point out that I would advise against using subtraction in the comparison. Consider an Order with a refund. If you have `-2000000000` for oldOrder, and `1000000000` for newOrder, yours would have `old-new = -3000000000` but would overflow into positive territory, when the result really should be negative.

Comment: @glowcoder: Fair point. I always get comparators the wrong way around :)

Comment: I'm tempted to say "If you know the input will never be negative, or in a range that can cause such an overflow it's okay" but then I think... man if I had a dollar for every time the requirements said "The input will never be _____" and it turned out they were, then I wouldn't need my day job :-)